# How to record the terminal on a server?

Tags: command-line, server, desktop-recording

I enjoy recording screencasts in my spare time, and was hoping to get going recording some Ubuntu stuff.

I have a machine running Ubuntu Server.

Is there any easy way to record the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php), also, here's a [comparison of screencasting software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_screencasting_software).

If you don't have any GUI you might want to use this script (it's part of the `util-linux-ng` package):

```
user@srv % script logfile
Script started, file is logfile
user@srv % echo test
test
user@srv % exit
Script done, file is logfile
```

You'll find a recording of this session in logfile.

To track a SSH session in the same fashion you can use tee:

```
user@srv % ssh host | tee -a sshlog
```

However, both ways just dump commands and outputs, without any time assignments. So it's not applicable to record videos.

I recommend to use something like VirtualBox or VMware and record the windows with virtual machines inside...

Answer (score 5):

## [ttyrec](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ttyrec/)

ttyrec allows you to record your terminal sessions easily. However, they are recorded in a special format (not video), but the resulting files are smaller, and as such easily transferable.

I use [playterm.org](http://playterm.org/) as a hosting for my ttyrec files. It allows you to view your terminal recordings over a browser (as if it were a video).

### Steps

#### Recording

```
sudo apt-get install ttyrec
ttyrec
#Type your commands
git init #Example command
exit
```

A ttyrec session is similar to a screen session, except that it is recorded. After your recording is complete, a file with `.tty` extension will be present in your directory. You can upload that file to playterm, or pass people a download link.

#### Playing

To play the file, they'd need to use the `ttyplay` command. Just use `ttyplay file.tty` and it should play your terminal.

### Editing

Since you are comfortable with adding audio later, I'd recommend copying the ttyrec file to a normal ubuntu desktop, and playing the recording (using `ttyplay`) while recording it using a screencasting session. You can record your voiceovers at the same time.

References:

- [ttyrec Home Page](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/index.html.en)
- [ttyrec man page](http://manpg.es/ttyrec)

Answer (score 5):

## [asciinema.org](https://asciinema.org/) (earlier ascii.io)

> asciinema [as-kee-nuh-muh] is a free and open source solution for recording terminal sessions and sharing them on the web.
>
> It is fully [open-source](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema.org) platform with aim of being a "go to" place for terminal users wanting to share their hackery. Web based player is an implementation of VT100/VT102 ANSI terminal, supporting most ANSI sequences, all text attributes and 256 colors.

### Installation for Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:zanchey/
sudo apt-get 
sudo apt-get install asciinema
```

It also supports other distros and even BSD/Mac systems. [Installation Instructions](https://asciinema.org/docs/installation)

Start recording with `asciinema rec`. If you want to upload recordings from command line, run `asciinema upload` to upload your recording.

More instructions on the help page (`asciinema`)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has shelr application:

```
sudo apt-get install shelr
man shelr
shelr record
```